# I need help selecting a specific jquery tab on page load

Tags: php, jquery, tabs

I need to be about to tell a page when it loads which jquery tab to use as the selected / active tab -- I've tried all the solutions I've found here, and have searched elsewhere extensively, but I'm handicapped by knowing very little about js and jquery. I'm also under a severe time crunch, so if anyone can help me I would be extremely grateful.

Here is my code:
In the page head section, I have:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-tabs.js"></script>
```

and

```
<script>$(document).ready(function()
$("#tabs > ul").tabs();</script>
```

In the body, I have the tab div set up, with the tabs as li items (sample below), and everything works fine except that I can't seem to select a tab programmatically.

```
li class="tabstuff"><a class="tabstuff" href="#tab1"><span>First Tab</span></a></li>
```

I haven't even been able to force my second tab to select on page load when I've tried using the code I saw in one of your question posts:

First I got the index of the tab I wanted (which I know worked, because I displayed it to myself using an alert box), using this:

```
    var index = $('#tabs a[href="#tab2"]').parent().index();
```

Then I tried each of these two methods (separately):

```
$("#tabs").tabs("option", "active", index);
```

I also tried:

```
$('#tabs').tabs('select', index);
```

Nothing works, and I don't know enough about jquery to see where I'm going wrong.

A second issue is how to tell the function which tab to select and display as active on page load. I can pass in a post or get variable, but I've tested code I found that says I can use this:

```
var qry = window.location.search;
if (qry.indexOf("showlist=yes") > 0) {
  //I added an alert box here and it never got triggered
  }
```

to check for a post or get variable, and that doesn't seem to work either.

My web page builds the html via php, but I don't yet understand enough about triggering a jquery function to know how to do that anywhere except on page load or an onclick/onchange event.

Thanks for any help anyone can give!

Comment: `$( ".selector" ).tabs({ active: 1 });` or `$( ".selector" ).tabs( "option", "active", 1 );`

Answer (score 1):

In order to select a different tab than the first you have to do

```
$("#tabs").tabs({ active: 2 });
```

Where `2` can be changed by any index you want

Comment: Beat me to it! Absolutely correct! Also, might wanna take a look at a [**blog i wrote on tabs**](http://spyk3lc.blogspot.com/2012/08/jqueryjqueryui-help-tabs-get-currently.html). Very helpful in getting the tabs and panels you want when needed!